# Python NLTK NGrams Error

Tags: python, nltk, assertion, n-gram

I'm running a code to get the perplexity, number of ngrams from a text corpus. While doing it, I got a weird error saying:

```
C:\Users\Rosenkrantz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2>python ai7.py
C:\Users\Rosenkrantz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication2>python ai7.py
47510
203044
308837
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ai7.py", line 95, in <module>
    tt=NgramModel(1, tText, estimator)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\model\ngram.py", line 81, in __init__
    assert(isinstance(pad_left, bool))
AssertionError
```

The Code I am Running to get this is:

```
f_in = open("science.txt", 'r');
ln = f_in.read()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(ln)
tText = Text(words)
tt=NgramModel(1, tText, estimator)
tt1=NgramModel(2, tText1, estimator)
tt2=NgramModel(3, tText2, estimator)
```

All the imports seem to be proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're calling `NgramModel` with the right arguments? Looking at the [source for the current version of NLTK](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/master/nltk/model/ngram.py), `NgramModel` looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, n, train, pad_left=True, pad_right=False,
                 estimator=None, *estimator_args, **estimator_kwargs):
```

Which doesn't seem to match up to how you're calling the function. What is `estimator` in your code? Because you're currently passing `estimator` as the `pad_left` argument.